# Stack overflow error trying to Binary Fold Left in Java

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I'm getting a stack overflow error when attempting to run this code. Can someone please help me debug it?

```
static <U> U binFoldLeft(U e, List<U>l, BiFunction<U,U,U> f){
    U result = e;

    f.apply(binFoldLeft(result, (l.subList(0, l.size()/2)), f),                 
            binFoldLeft(result, (l.subList(l.size()/2, l.size())),f)); 
    return result;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the base case to end the recursion. As written, `binFoldLeft` always calls itself twice, even if `l` is empty.

Comment: Can you please explain what is binFoldLeft?? I tried searching over internet, but could not get the description on what this function does?

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta that's the name that the OP gave to the function that he wrote and used in his question. It's not a standard library function or anything like that.